# Configure nginx for max-age=0 requests

Tags: nginx, http, reverse-proxy, cache

I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy with `proxy_cache`. The back-end is setting `cache-control` response headers which makes nginx serve responses from cache when possible.

However I would like to allow clients to bypass the cache by setting a request header `Cache-Control:max-age=0`. This way users can get a fresh copy by hitting `CTRL+R` in browser. By default, nginx seems to ignore the `Cache-Control` request header.

How can I configure nginx to fetch a fresh copy from the back-end and update the cache whenever a client requests a resource with `Cache-Control:max-age=0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use **[`proxy_cache_bypass`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cache_bypass)**.

```
proxy_cache_bypass  $http_cache_control;
```

This will cause nginx to fetch a fresh copy of the document in the presence of the `Cache-Control` header in the HTTP request from the client.

Note that the resulting response from the backend is still eligible for caching.  If you want to disqualify it from being cached, use the same arguments with the [`proxy_no_cache`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_nocache) directive, too.

Source: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_cache_bypass

---

If you specifically want to only bypass the cache when the client has `Cache-Control: max-age=0` in the headers (e.g. to explicitly not support another variant, `Cache-Control: no-cache`, which is actually supposedly a stronger preference for a fresh copy of the page than `max-age=0` is), then you can use the following, which I won't recommend due to such limitation:

```
set $cc_ma  0;
if ($http_cache_control = "max-age=0") {    # honour ⌘R, ignore ⇧⌘R (yes, bad idea!)
    set $cc_ma  1;
}
proxy_cache_bypass  $cc_ma;
```

---

BTW, there's also `Pragma: no-cache`, which this obviously won't account for, although in my limited set of experiments, it's always accompanied by a `Cache-Control: no-cache`, so, the original one-liner would probably do the best job.

As a note, SeaMonkey sends `Cache-Control: max-age=0` when you click *Reload* or <kbd>⌘R</kbd>, and `Pragma: no-cache\r\nCache-Control: no-cache` when you <kbd>Shift</kbd> *Reload* or <kbd>⇧⌘R</kbd>.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what `$http_cache_control` does in this case? Does it bypass the cache for any value of `Cache-Control`? Also I'd like to *update* the cache, not just bypass it.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it does, according to http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_cache_bypass.  If you don't want the response to be eligible for caching, you'd have to also use the `proxy_no_cache` directive.

Comment: Cool. But isn't `$http_cache_control` overly general? I.e. are there no possible values of the `cache-control` header which imply that the resource *should* be taken from cache?

Comment: You could try creating an intermediate variable, based on some `if` statements against whichever header and content you want, and then use that variable as the cache bypass string.

Comment: Could you perhaps add an example to your answer for the case `Cache-Control:max-age=0`?

Comment: There you go: `set $cc_ma 0;
 if ($http_cache_control = "max-age=0") {
  set $cc_ma 1;
 }
 proxy_cache_bypass $cc_ma;`